# Android Kotlin: Groupie RecyclerView All Items Added To The Same Expandable Item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablelistview

First, my question is same with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506416/groupie-recyclerview-all-items-added-to-the-same-expandable-item). But my code is different, and I try to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506416/groupie-recyclerview-all-items-added-to-the-same-expandable-item) but not solve my problem.

So my question is, I would like to have this:

- Header 1

  - Child header 1
  - Child header 1
  - Child header 1
- Header 2

  - Child header 2
  - Child header 2

I have this instead:

- Header 1

  - Child header 1
  - Child header 1
  - Child header 1
  - Child header 2
  - Child header 2
- header 2

  - Child header 1
  - Child header 1
  - Child header 1
  - Child header 2
  - Child header 2

This is my code for `ParentItemAdapter`

```
class ParentItemAdapter(private val titlePlan: String?, private val fragment: FragmentActivity) :
    Item(), ExpandableItem {
    private lateinit var expandableGroup: ExpandableGroup

    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.root.tvTitlePlan.text =
            String.format(fragment.getString(R.string.plan), titlePlan)
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            expandableGroup.onToggleExpanded()
            changeStuff(viewHolder)
        }

    }

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.item_benefit_corporate_parent
    }

    private fun changeStuff(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder) {
        viewHolder.root.indicator.apply {
            setImageResource(
                if (expandableGroup.isExpanded) R.drawable.ic_arrow_up_red
                else R.drawable.ic_arrow_down_red
            )
        }
    }

    override fun setExpandableGroup(onToggleListener: ExpandableGroup) {
        this.expandableGroup = onToggleListener
    }

}
```

This is my code for `ChildItemAdapter`

```
class ChildItemAdapter(
    private val guarantee: String?,
    private val statusBenefit: String?,
    private val benefitLimit: Long?
) : Item() {

    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.root.tvTitleGuaranteeChild.text = guarantee
        viewHolder.root.tvStatusChild.text = statusBenefit
        viewHolder.root.tvBenefitLimitChild.text = benefitLimit?.applyThousandSeparator()
    }

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.item_benefit_corporate_child
    }

}
```

And this is my Fragment.

```
class CorporateBenefitFragment :
    BaseFragment<FragmentCorporateBenefitBinding, CorporateBenefitViewModel>() {

    private val groupAdapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()

    ...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        ...

        initRecyclerView()

        vm.getBenefitCorporate(regSpaj, msteInsured)
        vm.benefit.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            it?.let {
                when (it) {
                    ...
                    is ResultState.HasData -> {
                        ...
                        mappingData(it.data)
                    }
                    ...
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        val divider =
            DividerItemDecoration(binding.expandableBenefit.context, layoutManager.orientation)
        binding.expandableBenefit.layoutManager = layoutManager
        binding.expandableBenefit.adapter = groupAdapter
        binding.expandableBenefit.addItemDecoration(divider)
    }

    private fun mappingData(data: List<Benefit>) {
        val parentList = mutableListOf<ParentItemAdapter>()
        val childList = mutableListOf<ChildItemAdapter>()
        for (i in data) {
            parentList.add(ParentItemAdapter(i.namePlan, requireActivity()))
            for (a in i.detailBenefit) {
                childList.add(ChildItemAdapter(a.kindOfGuarantee, a.benefitStatus, a.benefitLimit))
            }
        }

        groupAdapter.apply {
            for (i in parentList) {
                this += ExpandableGroup(i).apply {
                    for (j in childList) { // I think the problem was here, but I don't know how to fix it
                        add(j)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this code.

```
private fun mappingData(data: List<Benefit>) {
        val parentList = mutableListOf<ParentItemAdapter>()
        for (i in data) {
            parentList.add(ParentItemAdapter(i.namePlan, requireActivity()))
        }
        groupAdapter.apply {
            for (i in 0 until parentList.size) {
                this += ExpandableGroup(parentList[i]).apply {
                    for (j in data[i].detailBenefit) {
                        add(ChildItemAdapter(j.kindOfGuarantee, j.benefitStatus, j.benefitLimit))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

or with this

```
private fun mappingData(data: List<Benefit>) {
        for (i in data) {
            val parentItem = ParentItemAdapter(i.namePlan, requireActivity())
            val expandableGroup = ExpandableGroup(parentItem, false)
            for (j in i.detailBenefit) {
                val childItem = ChildItemAdapter(j.kindOfGuarantee, j.benefitStatus, j.benefitLimit)
                expandableGroup.add(Section(childItem))
            }
            groupAdapter.add(expandableGroup)
        }
    }
```